# Configuring Squid to not log TCP connections (lots of "error:transaction-end-before-headers" showing up in logs)

Tags: squid, centos8

We run Squid proxies in GCP, and are in the process of migrating from CentOS 7 to 8.   I'm working on using the GCP Internal L4 load balancer to improve redundancy/failover, and have configured a basic TCP healthcheck which is working fine.

However, it looks like Squid version 4 logs TCP connections.  So, every 10 seconds I get 3 entries added to /var/log/squid/access.log:

```
1618013711.836      0 35.191.10.117 NONE/000 0 NONE error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
1618013712.256      0 35.191.9.223 NONE/000 0 NONE error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
1618013712.484      0 35.191.10.121 NONE/000 0 NONE error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
```

This would generate 25,920 lines a day of logs, which I'd like to avoid.  Is there a way to configure Squid to not do this?  The default squid.conf file didn't have much as far as documentation/explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Squid ACL documentation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/) you can try to add the following ACL in your Squid config:

```
acl hasRequest has request
```

Then log those transactions that have request:

```
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log hasRequest
```

Or exclude all without request:

```
access_log none !hasRequest
```

Answer (score 1):

This did work:

```
acl hasRequest has request
access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log hasRequest
```